# Javascript (lodash) function to get an ordered array of object values

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, function, lodash

(The title above might be misleading and I'm open to suggestions on how to improve it.)

What I want is a function that takes an `Array` and an `Object` as arguments and produces an array containing the values of the object in the order specified by the array.  I.e. the first argument (the array) can be thought of as a schema that defines the order in which the object's values should be stored in the resulting array.

I.e.:

```
var arrPersonSchema = [
  'name',
  'age',
  'height'
];

var objPerson = {
  'name': 'fred',
  'age': 35,
  'height': 60
};

var objPerson2 = {
  'age': 22,
  'name': 'jane'
};

function orderedValues(arrSchema, obj) {
  var arrResult = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arrSchema.length; i++) 
    arrResult[i] = obj[arrSchema[i]];
  return arrResult;
}

orderedValues(arrPersonSchema, objPerson);
// → [ 'fred', 35, 60]

orderedValues(arrPersonSchema, objPerson2);
// → [ 'jane', 22, undefined]
```

Now obviously the code above produces the desired result, but my question is whether or not there is a more efficient (faster) method to achieve the same result using lodash or a similar performance enhanced javascript library (or even a fast native implementation).

From a certain perspective, I am asking for an *inverse* of the two-array form of the lodash function [_.zipObject](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject). The function has two forms:

(A) Takes a single 2D array (this is the inverse of [_.pairs](https://lodash.com/docs#pairs))

```
_.zipObject( [['fred', 30], ['barney', 40]] );
// → { 'fred': 30, 'barney': 40 }
```

(B) Takes two 1D arrays: (this is the one for which I want the inverse)

```
_.zipObject( ['fred', 'barney'],  [30, 40] );
// → { 'fred': 30, 'barney': 40 }
```

It is the **second form** which I am referring to. One could use this for example to produce an object given the schema array and an array of values. I.e.:

```
_.zipObject(arrPersonSchema, ['fred', 35, 60]);
// → { 'name': 'fred',  'age': 35,  'height': 60 }
```

Note that the lodash function [_.values](https://lodash.com/docs#values) is **not** an acceptable answer. While it is true that it produces an array of values, the order of values is "not guaranteed". The important aspect of the function I am looking for is that the order of values in the resulting array is **explicitly defined** by the schema, and does not rely on any *implicit* ordering of properties, either within the object (e.g. based on the manner in which the object was constructed etc) or any unofficial implimentation details of the function etc.

## Update

Thanks to all who responded. I was surprised at Bergi's suggestion that my implementation (which I assumed was "naive") was likely to be the fastest option.  But I took Bergi's advice and benchmarked the 4 suggestions I received. These results are by no means authoritative. I simply used Chrome DevTools Javascript CPU profiler and ran 100000 trials for each (3 different objects per trial). You can see the Plunker I used to setup the benchmark [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VbmsLIsNihhaWurL7NNN).

Here are the results:

```
simpleLoop:   393 ms
lodashAt:     917 ms
nativeMap:    719 ms
modArgs:    13741 ms
```

- `simpleLoop` is the function I wrote (aka `orderedValues`)
- `lodashAt` is the lodash function `_.at()` suggested by [Adam Boduch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4606858/adam-boduch)
- `nativeMap` is the ES5 version of the function recommended by [Klaster_1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333777/klaster-1)
- `modArgs` is the function [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) listed (with the caveat that it would probably NOT be faster than my function.)

I was a bit unsure about whose answer to select, because I actually posed a couple different questions at once. Adam Boduch gave the best lodash-based answer, and it was exactly what I was looking for as an "inverse" to the zipObject function. Bergi's lodash function was not as concise (and it turned out to be MUCH slower). However, Bergi pointed out that my simple `orderedValues` function was probably the fastest, and he was right. Looking back at my question,  especially the line that includes "...my question is whether or not there is a more efficient (faster) method...", it appears that Bergi actually answered it best by pointing out that there really wasn't a faster method than the one I proposed.  So although Adam Boduch was spot-on with his answer, I've decided to select Bergi's. Thanks again to all!

Comment: Why not just to use `const f = (order, object) => order.map(key => object[key])` or ES5 equivalent?

Comment: Um, you've already written that *fast native implementation* and called it `orderedValues`?! There's hardly anything to make this better. Lodash also just put their pants on one leg at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function orderedValues(arrSchema, obj) {
>   var arrResult = [];
>   for(var i = 0; i < arrSchema.length; i++) 
>     arrResult[i] = obj[arrSchema[i]];
>   return arrResult;
> }
> ```

That's as good as it gets. It's native JS, and pretty fast.

If you insist on using lodash, here you go:

```
var orderedValues = _.modArgs(_.map, [_.identity, _.propertyOf])
```

This might make your code shorter and more expressive, but hardly faster. You can benchmark them yourself if you want.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at) for this:

```
_.at(objPerson, arrPersonSchema);
// → ["fred", 35, 60]

_.at(objPerson2, arrPersonSchema)
// → ["jane", 22, undefined]
```